# Best way for converting linq to entity query to strongly typed ObservableCollection

Tags: wpf, linq-to-entities, observablecollection

I am learning these days Entity Framework 5.
I developing WPF application which based on MVVM and PRISM.
In order to get property changed notifications I am using `ObservableCollection` for keep my data.

I have problem when I use linq to entity projection and I am not sure what is the best solution for it.

As you know, when you execute projection through linq to entity you get anonymous type that no one know out the scope of the method. I searched how to make this query strongly typed.

I seen some discussions about this issue but I couldn`t find what is the best approach.

I seen 3 different solutions:

1. using QueryView
2. using Define Query
3. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/c6b8375a-2684-4020-bbcc-24433baf997b

Number 3 is the simplest one and seen like exactly what I need but I know that Reflection is "high cost" operation so it return me to the question what is the best approach for this problem? any other solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not project to an anonymous type but to named type.

```
var query = from c in Customers 
            join o in Orders on c.CustomerID equals o.CustomerID
            select new OrderDto {
                                    customer_name = c.CompanyName,
                                    order_date = o.OrderDate,
                                    order_Id = o.OrderID
                                };
```

Which uses a simple class `OrderDto`. So that's none of your options.

Side note: you can probably use navigation properties:

```
var query = from o in Orders
            select new OrderDto {
                                    customer_name = o.Customer.CompanyName,
                                    order_date = o.OrderDate,
                                    order_Id = o.OrderID
                                };
```

and EF will figure out how to join.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer. I will try it in 4-5 hours and report.
I`m wondering, How you compare this method to solution number 3? Is it better than the "reflection solution"?

Comment: IMO, yes it is. Solutions with reflection are slow and needlessly complex. It's my opinion that reflection should only be used if there's absolutely no alternative.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use:

I use VB:

```
Dim ObjectQuery As IQueryable(Of YourObject) = CType((From c In YourContext.objects Select c), IQueryable(Of YourObject))
Return New ObservableCollection(Of YourObject)(ObjectQuery)
```

a simple version of the above based on a client table in C# without the CType.  I used a vb to C# converter so it might need to be adjusted

```
IQueryable<client> ClientQuery = from c in ftcContext.clients select c;
return new ObservableCollection<client>(ClientQuery);
```

Comment: I`m C# developer. What is "YourObject"?
I don`t have specific object for this projection, This projection return a mix of columns of my other entities

Comment: yourobject is the name of an entity framework entity.  so if you have a table in your database called client it would look like this:

Dim ClientQuery As IQueryable(Of client) = CType((From c In ftcContext.clients Select c), IQueryable(Of client))
                Return New ObservableCollection(Of client)(ClientQuery)

Comment: @OFir `Of X` is VB's syntax for the C# Generic syntax `<X>`. You'll need a strong class of some sort.

Comment: But if I do projection with "join" I`m returning a mixture of columns from different entities.

For example, look at the next query:

"var query = from c in Customers
            join o in Orders
　　　　　　　on c.CustomerID equals o.CustomerID
　　　　　　　select new {customer_name = c.CompanyName,　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　 
　　　　　　　  　　　　　 order_date = o.OrderDate,
　　　　　　　　  　　　　 order_Id = o.OrderID}; "

How can you solve it by your suggestion?