# WPF, LINQ and ObservableCollections

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

I'm new to WPF and I'm struggling. I need to populate a combobox with data from a database. I'm attempting to use LINQ to retrieve the data into an ObservableCollection which I am binding to through the XAML. Simple probably for everyone except me. I'm getting an error "The entity or complex type '' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query." when I attempt to populate the collection. What am I doing wrong? I've looked at several different questions, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15353579/best-way-for-converting-linq-to-entity-query-to-strongly-typed-observablecollect) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465285/cast-linq-result-to-observablecollection), but without any luck. This seems so simple. What am I doing wrong?

Here is what my ViewModel looks like:

```
public class MainViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private ObservableCollection<Customer> _customers;
    public ObservableCollection<Customer> Customers
    {
        get { return _customers; }
        set
        {
            if ( value != _customers )
            {
                _customers = value;
                OnPropertyChanged( "Customers" );
            }
        }
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        // populate the customers combo
        using ( var db = new DataContext() )
        {
            var customer = ( from c in db.Customers
                           where c.Active == true
                           select new Customer
                           {
                               CustomerID = c.CustomerID,
                               Name = c.Name
                           } );
            // Error Here
            Customers = new ObservableCollection<Customer>( customer.ToList() );
            // Tried this too
            //var Query = db.Customers.Select( c => new Customer() { Name=c.Name, CustomerID=c.CustomerID } ).ToList<Customer>();
            //Customers = new ObservableCollection<Customer>(Query);
        }
    } 
}
```

EDIT:
Here is a copy of the Customer class:

```
namespace EF_HVAC_Estimator.Models
{
    [Table( "Customers" )]
    public class Customer : ModelBase
    {
        [Key]
        public int CustomerID { get; set; }

        public int EmployeeID { get; set; }

        [StringLength( 100 )]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [StringLength( 100 )]
        public string Address { get; set; }

        [StringLength( 100 )]
        public string City { get; set; }

        public int StateID { get; set; }

        [StringLength( 10 )]
        public string Zip { get; set; }

        [StringLength( 15 )]
        public string Phone { get; set; }

        [StringLength( 15 )]
        public string Fax { get; set; }

        [StringLength( 50 )]
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

        public bool Active { get; set; }

        public List<Estimate> Estimates { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Provide some details on the class Customer?

Comment: Also check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325797/the-entity-cannot-be-constructed-in-a-linq-to-entities-query

Comment: An observable collection is not a requirement to showing/binding a list. Only use an observable collection if you need to be notified if a list changes, additions/deletions. Since it doesn't appear that you need the overhead of the observable collection, just use a List<Customer> instead.

Comment: Loop thru db.Customers and add to Customers in the loop

Comment: Thanks @PraveenPaulose, I added the Customers class.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're getting a collection of the Entity `Customer` and trying to cast it into `Customer`.  Perhaps it is getting confused.

Linq uses deferred execution and is trying to pass the query down to the database.  It is the `ToList()` method that is triggering the execution.  If the 2 customer classes (the query and the type in the observable collection) are really the same entity, just fill the collection with the result.

Note that unless you're dynamically adding/removing items from the collection, there may be no reason to use an `ObservableCollection`.  A `List<Customer>` will suffice.  Are the `Customer` classes intended to be the same, or is the `ObservableCollection` a different `Customer` class?  Specifying the namespace may help, if that is the case.

```
using(var db = new DataContext())
{
  Customers = db.Customers
                .Where(c => c.Active == true).ToList();
}
```

[EDIT]
Alright then... simply iterate over the list to populate... should be the same result.  I think the problem was lying in the cast you were doing during the Linq select.

```
using(var db = new DataContext())
{
    var custs = db.Customers
                  .Where(c => c.Active == true).ToList();

    if(Customers == null)
        Customers = new ObservableCollection<Customer>();
    foreach (var cust in custs)
    {
        Customers.Add(cust);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Mark W, changing the code to use a list works, but there will be some adding/removing going on so in the end I will need to use an ObservableCollection.